# MATLAB uipanel child visiable

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

quick question on uipanels/button groups, how can i make one item (a radio button) with in the uipanel visible/not visible...
the code "set(handles.uibatspanel,'visible','off')" makes the panel itself visible or not, but i want the radio button "raido2bats" within this panel to be visiable/not visiable

Many Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 3):

Use the same code with the handle to the radio button `uicontrol`, rather than the handle to the `uipanel` itself.

Comment: Please could you go in to a little more detail ie the code, this GUI is a new thing to me, it breaks when the radio button is within the panel, thank you

Comment: @user2962403 - you said that the code `set(handles.uibatspanel, 'visible', 'off')` makes the panel itself visible, but you only want the radio button to turn invisible. Instead of setting the `handles.uiabtspanel` handle, set `handles.raido2bats` instead.

Comment: @user2962403 Exactly what Dang Khoa said.